# Which side of a 2d curve is a point on?

Tags: bezier-curve

Given a point $Q$ and $2d$ Cubic Bezier Curve:  $$P = A(1-t)^3 + 3Bt(1-t)^2 + 3Ct^2(1-t) + Dt^3$$

Is there a way to know which side of the curve the point lies on? I know that the term "side" is a bit strange since there can be a loop, but I'm wondering if answering this question might be more easily done than finding a points distance to the curve, which would require solving a cubic equation.

I found info about finding the distance via a cubic root here: http://www.pouet.net/topic.php?which=9119&page=1

That isn't super complex, but if answering a side question makes things easier, I'm hoping it'll extend to higher order curves or higher dimension curves.

If this is more easily solved with a quadratic curve instead of a cubic bezier curve that would also be helpful!

$$P = A(1-t)^2 + 2Bt(1-t) + Ct^2$$

Thanks for any info!!

Comment: Are you concerned only about the part of the curve for $0\le t\le 1$ or for all $t$?

Comment: 0 to 1 mainly, but if it's easier to get an answer for all t, that is fine too!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can address this by the method of implicitization, i.e. eliminating the parameter $t$ to obtain an implicit form of the equation, $F(x,y)=0$, where $F$ is a bivariate polynomial. The curve partitions the plane in regions $>0$ and $<0$, telling you on what side you are.

In the case of a Bézier cubic, the polynomial is of cubic order. (A quadratic Bézier yields a conic.)

You will find the analytical result here: http://www.mare.ee/indrek/misc/2d.pdf, section "1.4.2 Implicitization of the cubic bezier curve".

Comment: Do you know where i can find any basic information on re-parameterization?  I haven't encountered this before, of removing the t and coming out with an f(x,y) and I'd like to learn some intuition about it but haven't been able to find any information online.  Thank you so much for your answer btw!

Comment: You can read this article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_equation (in particular 4. and 5.)

Answer (score 3):

I ended up finding a solution to this that I like better than implicitization (I'm a better programmer than I am a mathematician!).  I am trying to use this in a computer graphics situation, and had found a paper that talked about how to use graphics hardware to draw a triangle in a specific way to make it so you could use the $u,v$ texture coordinates to test if a point was inside or outside of the halfspace defined by the curve.

You can see it here: [Resolution Independent Curve Rendering using Programmable Graphics Hardware](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/cloop/LoopBlinn05.pdf)

In my situation, I didn't have the ability to do it the way they did because I'm not doing triangle rendering, I'm doing an operation per pixel.

So, to solve it, I ended up just calculating the barycentric coordinates of a point within the triangle defined by the control points, and did the technique manually.

It ended up working pretty well.  Here's the technique in action, implemented in GLSL at shadertoy: [Shadertoy: 2D Quadratic Bezier II](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4tj3Dy)